# (Symfony 4) Liip/Imagine can't find my uploaded image

Tags: image, file, path, upload

I have no problem uploading my images to my S3 server (so I know that my image path is legitimate), but when I try to use the Liip/Imagine service to to create some re-sized images, Liip/Imagine can't find my uploaded image.

I do a dump of the image path as follows:

```
$idFile = $form['idFile']->getData();
dump($idFile);
die();
```

Here is what the dump looks like:

```
ProfileController.php on line 340:
UploadedFile {#64 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "file-name.png"
  -mimeType: "image/png"
  -error: 0
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "php09sJr3"
  basename: "php09sJr3"
  pathname: "/tmp/php09sJr3"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/php09sJr3"
  aTime: 2019-02-24 22:54:00
  mTime: 2019-02-24 22:54:00
  cTime: 2019-02-24 22:54:00
  inode: 12586620
  size: 97901
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 997
  group: 995
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

I know that this path (/tmp/php09sJr3) is legitimate because my files all upload perfectly to my S3 bucket, but when I try to create the thumbnails in my controller:

```
public function saveProfileEditAction(Request $request, FilterService $imagine)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(UserProfileType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())        {
        $idFile = $form['idFile']->getData();

        if ($idFile != null){
            // this command right here 
            $resourcePath = $imagine->getUrlOfFilteredImage($idFile->getPathName(), 'my_thumb');
```

I get the following error:

```
Source image not resolvable "/tmp/php09sJr3" in root path(s) "/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/public"
```

What makes this more confusing is that when I check, there is nothing in `/tmp` or `/var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/public/tmp`, however my files still perfectly upload to S3.

Here is my configuration liip_imagine.yaml file:

```
liip_imagine :
    # configure resolvers
    resolvers :
        # setup the default resolver
        default :
            # use the default web path
            web_path : ~
    # your filter sets are defined here
    filter_sets :
        # use the default cache configuration
        cache : ~
        # the name of the "filter set"
        my_thumb :
            # adjust the image quality to 75%
            quality : 75
            # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
            filters :
                # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
                # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
                thumbnail  : { size : [120, 90], mode : outbound }
                thumb_square :  { size : [300, 300], mode : outbound }
                thumb_rectangle_md : { size : [670, 400], mode : outbound }
                thumb_hd : { size : [1920, 1080], mode : outbound }
                # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
                # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
                background : { size : [124, 94], position : center, color : '#000000' }
```

How do I properly tell Liip/Imagine the file path to my uploaded file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add this to your yaml configuration file (mine is liip_imagine.yaml):

```
loaders:
    default:
        filesystem:
            data_root: "/"
```

So within the scope of the file it will look like:

```
liip_imagine :
    # configure resolvers
    resolvers :
        # setup the default resolver
        default :
            # use the default web path
            web_path : ~
# !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!START!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    loaders:
        default:
            filesystem:
                data_root: "/"
# !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!END!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    # your filter sets are defined here
    filter_sets :
        # use the default cache configuration
        cache : ~
        # the name of the "filter set"
        my_thumb :
            # adjust the image quality to 75%
            quality : 75
            # list of transformations to apply (the "filters")
            filters :
                # create a thumbnail: set size to 120x90 and use the "outbound" mode
                # to crop the image when the size ratio of the input differs
                thumbnail  : { size : [120, 90], mode : outbound }
                resize : { size : [670, 400], mode : outbound }
                # create a 2px black border: center the thumbnail on a black background
                # 4px larger to create a 2px border around the final image
                background : { size : [124, 94], position : center, color : '#000000' }
```

Liip will then create the thumbnail, resize, etc... and move the file to:

```
http://www.yourwebsite.com/media/cache/my_thumb/tmp/phpSQFUF1
```

Technically within your server it will be the `/public/media/cache/my_thumb/tmp` folder in your root folder.